# append onclick function to div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an on click function to a div using these lines of code but the click event doesnt trigger the alert.

```
var str="<script>$(this).on(\"click\",function(){alert('hello');})";
str+="<";
str+="/script>";
$("div:contains('Send')").last().append(str);
```

I've also tried `this` and `$(this)[0]` but these give me the error `this.on/ $(this)[0].on is not a function`
I don't know what Im doing wrong and would appreciate any and all help on the matter.

Comment: `"<script>$(this).on(\"click\",function(){alert('hello');})";` what will this represent here?

Comment: im sorry I dont understand the question?

Comment: When you use `this`, it represents current object. So when you do obj.alert(), in alert, this will represent obj. Also for your case refer to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/66eq9em2/) for reference. Hope it helps.

Comment: `$("div:contains('Send')").last().on("click",function(){alert('hello');})` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't have to go through the trouble of creating strings for script. You can just use jquerys .on and register it with a click event.

```
$("div:contains('Send')").last().on("click", function () {
    alert('hello');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can add click event to all the div by using $("div") for selector (just remember to call the function after you load the div)

I have create an example of simple click function

```
$(".start").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("onClick");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7j6s2Lws/2/

The $(this) will identify which object is actually trigger the event, and choose it only. In my case, if you click on a div, it will change color (of it and only it)

Answer (score 0):

i would choose a slightly different approach. i hope i understood your problem right even though i dont really get what you want to achieve by putting `<script>` into your string here... maybe this helps:

**html**

```
<div id='container'>
    <button>Send</button>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var $container = $("div:contains('Send')");
var elementToAppend = "<div class='myClass' style='width:100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid red'>added dynamically ... click me</div>";

appendToContainer($container, elementToAppend);
$('.myClass').click(function($element) {
    alert(123);
});

function appendToContainer($container, element) {
    $container.append(element);
}
```

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/2pofLnb7/2/

Comment: if you just want to add a clickhandler to anything existing then have a look at the fiddle/js/line5